# Tree for PowerShell

Tags: recursion, tree, powershell

For anyone reading this old question, this module has evolved and improved a lot since then. It has been fully rewritten in C# and uploaded to the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSTree)! If you would like to try it out:

```bash
Install-Module PSTree -Scope CurrentUser
```

And, if you want to check out the source code: [PSTree GitHub](https://github.com/santysq/PSTree). This project is always open to collaborations and all feedback is appreciated!

---

This Module started as a fun coding exercise designed to emulate the [`tree`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree) command and also calculate the size of each folder based of the files size of that folder (non-recursive).

Now, completed and tested on Windows and Linux, I thought it would be nice to have it reviewed to see where it could be improved improved, or if there is something I could have missed and should fix.

If I'm failing to explain anything or make things clear, please let me know and I'll try to correct it. I would like to **thank you** upfront for taking the time to read this and I'm sorry for the length of the post.

### Helper Functions

#### `Indent`

Takes a `string` as input and based on `-Indent` argument, it returns the indented string. Example:

```
PS /> Indent ThisString -Indent 4

                ThisString
```

- Code

```
function Indent {
param(
    [String]$String,
    [Int]$Indent
)

    switch($Indent)
    {
        {-not $_} {
            return $String
        }
        Default {
            "$('    ' * $_)$String"
        }
    }
}
```

#### `SizeConvert`

This one is pretty straight forward, all credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40887001/15339544), I just modified it a bit:

```
PS /> SizeConvert 1024                   

1 Kb
PS /> SizeConvert (1024*1024)

1 Mb
```

- Code

```
function SizeConvert($Size) {
    $suffix = "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB"
    $index = 0
    while ($Size -ge 1kb) 
    {
        $Size /= 1kb
        $index++
    }
    [string]::Format(
        '{0:0.##} {1}',
        $Size, $suffix[$index]
    )
}
```

#### `Get-FolderRecursive`

This function is the heart, takes a folder's path as input and will recurse through the sub-folders, the output received by it is what we see on the `$outObject` scriptblock.

**EXAMPLE**

```
PS /> Get-FolderRecursive /etc/ -Depth 2 -EA SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -First 5 | Format-Table

Nesting Hierarchy        Size      RawSize FullName          Parent    Creat....
------- ---------        ----      ------- --------          ------    -----....
      0 etc              349.83 KB  358229 /etc/             /         12/14....
      1     acpi         1.83 KB      1872 /etc/acpi         /etc      8/14/....
      2         events   1.44 KB      1470 /etc/acpi/events  /etc/acpi 8/14/....
      1     alternatives 5.08 KB      5201 /etc/alternatives /etc      3/28/....
      1     apache2      0 B               /etc/apache2      /etc      8/14/....
```

- Code

```
function Get-FolderRecursive {
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [string]$Path,
    [int]$Nesting = 0,
    [int]$Depth,
    [switch]$Deep,
    [switch]$Force
)

    $outObject = {
        param($Nesting, $folder)
        
        $files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $folder.FullName -File -Force
        $size = ($files | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum
        
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Nesting        = $Nesting
            Hierarchy      = Indent -String $folder.Name -Indent $Nesting
            Size           = SizeConvert $size
            RawSize        = $size
            FullName       = $folder.FullName
            Parent         = $folder.Parent
            CreationTime   = $folder.CreationTime
            LastAccessTime = $folder.LastAccessTime
            LastWriteTime  = $folder.LastWriteTime
        }
    }

    if(-not $Nesting)
    {
        $parent = Get-Item -LiteralPath $Path
        & $outObject -Nesting $Nesting -Folder $parent
    }

    $Nesting++

    $folders = if($Force.IsPresent)
    {
        Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Path -Directory -Force
    }
    else
    {
        Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Path -Directory
    }

    foreach($folder in $folders)
    {
        & $outObject -Nesting $Nesting -Folder $folder
        
        $PSBoundParameters.Path = $folder.FullName
        $PSBoundParameters.Nesting = $Nesting

        if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Depth'))
        {
            if($Nesting -lt $Depth)
            {
                Get-FolderRecursive @PSBoundParameters
            }
        }
        
        if($Deep.IsPresent)
        {
            Get-FolderRecursive @PSBoundParameters
        }
    }
}
```

#### `DrawHierarchy`

This function takes as input an `array` and will draw the hierarchy lines based on the arguments provided to `-PropertyName` and `-RecursionProperty`. This one is pretty hard for me to explain, and my only concern is understanding if the regex `└|\S` (`$corner` is `└` on the code) will suffice and in case it is not how could it be improved. Example using the result from before:

```
PS /> $result = Get-FolderRecursive /etc/ -Depth 2 -EA SilentlyContinue |Select-Object -First 5
PS /> DrawHierarchy -Array $result -PropertyName Hierarchy -RecursionProperty Nesting | Format-Table

Nesting Hierarchy        Size      RawSize FullName          Parent    Creat.....
------- ---------        ----      ------- --------          ------    -----.....
      0 etc              349.83 KB  358229 /etc/             /         12/14.....
      1 ├── acpi         1.83 KB      1872 /etc/acpi         /etc      8/14/.....
      2 │   └── events   1.44 KB      1470 /etc/acpi/events  /etc/acpi 8/14/.....
      1 ├── alternatives 5.08 KB      5201 /etc/alternatives /etc      3/28/.....
      1 └── apache2      0 B               /etc/apache2      /etc      8/14/.....
```

- Code

```
function DrawHierarchy {
param(
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Array,
    [string]$PropertyName,
    [string]$RecursionProperty
)
    # Had to do this because of Windows PowerShell Default Encoding
    # Not good at enconding stuff, probably a better way. Sorry for the ugliness :(
    $bytes = @(
        '226','148','148'
        '44','226','148'
        '128','44','226'
        '148','130','44'
        '226','148','156'
    )
    $corner, $horizontal, $pipe, $connector =
    [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($bytes).Split(',')
    $cornerConnector = "${corner}$(${horizontal}*2) "

    $Array | Group-Object $RecursionProperty |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | ForEach-Object {
            $_.$PropertyName = $_.$PropertyName -replace '\s{4}(?=\S)', $cornerConnector
        }
    }

    for($i = 1; $i -lt $Array.Count; $i++)
    {
        $index = $Array[$i].$PropertyName.IndexOf($corner)
        if($index -ge 0)
        {
            $z = $i - 1
            while($Array[$z].$PropertyName[$index] -notmatch "$corner|\S")
            {
                $replace = $Array[$z].$PropertyName.ToCharArray()
                $replace[$Index] = $pipe
                $Array[$z].$PropertyName = -join $replace
                $z--
            }
        
            if($Array[$z].$PropertyName[$index] -eq $corner)
            {
                $replace = $Array[$z].$PropertyName.ToCharArray()
                $replace[$Index] = $connector
                $Array[$z].$PropertyName = -join $replace
            }
        }
    }
    $Array
}
```

### Wrapper Function

#### `Get-PSTree`

Lastly, the wrapper, this function is in charge of parameter validation mainly and calling both `Get-FolderRecursive` and `DrawHierarchy` based on the arguments provided to **`-Path`** and **`-Depth`** or **`-Deep`** with **`-Force`** being optional.

- **PARAMETER**

| Parameter Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `-Path <string>` | Absolute or relative folder path. Alias: `FullName`, `PSPath` |
| `[-Depth <int>]` | Specifies the maximum level of recursion |
| `[-Deep <switch>]` | Recursion until maximum level is reached |
| `[-Force <switch>]` | Display hidden and system folders |
| `[<CommonParameters>]` | See [`about_CommonParameters`](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216) |

- **OUTPUTS `Object[]`**

```
Name           TypeNameOfValue
----           ---------------
Nesting        System.Int32
Hierarchy      System.String
Size           System.String
RawSize        System.Double
FullName       System.String
Parent         System.IO.DirectoryInfo
CreationTime   System.DateTime
LastAccessTime System.DateTime
LastWriteTime  System.DateTime
```

- Code

```
function Get-PSTree {
[cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Depth')]
[alias('gpstree')]
param(
    [parameter(
        Mandatory,
        ParameterSetName = 'Path',
        Position = 0
    )]
    [parameter(
        Mandatory,
        ParameterSetName = 'Depth',
        Position = 0
    )]
    [parameter(
        Mandatory,
        ParameterSetName = 'Max',
        Position = 0
    )]
    [alias('FullName', 'PSPath')]
    [ValidateScript({ 
        if(Test-Path $_ -PathType Container)
        {
            return $true
        }
        throw 'Invalid Folder Path'
    })]
    [string]$Path,
    [ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
    [parameter(
        ParameterSetName = 'Depth',
        Position = 1
    )]
    [int]$Depth = 3,
    [parameter(
        ParameterSetName = 'Max',
        Position = 1
    )]
    [switch]$Deep,
    [switch]$Force
)

    process
    {
        [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $pwd.ProviderPath
        $PSBoundParameters.Path = ([System.IO.FileInfo]$Path).FullName
        $DefaultProps = @(
            'Hierarchy'
            'Size'
        )
        [Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo[]]$standardMembers =
            [System.Management.Automation.PSPropertySet]::new(
                'DefaultDisplayPropertySet',
                [string[]]$DefaultProps
            )
        
        $hash = @{
            Name = 'PSStandardMembers'
            MemberType = 'MemberSet'
            Value = $standardMembers
        }
        
        $isDepthParam = $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Depth'
        $containsDepth = $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Depth')
        
        if($isDepthParam -and -not $containsDepth)
        {
            $PSBoundParameters.Add('Depth', $Depth)
        }

        $result = Get-FolderRecursive @PSBoundParameters

        $drawProps = @{
            Array = $result
            PropertyName = 'Hierarchy'
            RecursionProperty = 'Nesting'
        }

        DrawHierarchy @drawProps | ForEach-Object {
            $hash.InputObject = $_
            Add-Member @hash
        }

        $result
    }
}
```

#### EXAMPLES

- **`Get-PSTree .`** Gets the hierarchy and folder size of the current directory using **default Depth (3)**.
- **`Get-PSTree C:\users\user -Depth 10 -Force`** Gets the hierarchy and folder size, including hidden ones, of the `user` directory  with a maximum of **10** levels of recursion.
- **`Get-PSTree /home/user -Deep`:** Gets the hierarchy and folder size of the `user` directory and all folders below.

---

````
PS /etc> $hierarchy = gpstree . -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Depth 5
PS /etc> $hierarchy | Select -First 20                                

Hierarchy                              Size
---------                              ----
etc                                    349.3 Kb
├── acpi                               1.8 Kb
│   └── events                         1.4 Kb
├── alternatives                       5.1 Kb
├── apache2                            0 Bytes
│   ├── conf-available                 127 Bytes
│   └── mods-available                 156 Bytes
├── apm                                0 Bytes
│   ├── event.d                        2.9 Kb
│   ├── resume.d                       17 Bytes
│   ├── scripts.d                      228 Bytes
│   └── suspend.d                      17 Bytes
├── apparmor                           3.4 Kb
│   └── init                           0 Bytes
│       └── network-interface-security 33 Bytes
├── apparmor.d                         25.9 Kb
│   ├── abstractions                   91.1 Kb
│   │   ├── apparmor_api               2.4 Kb
│   │   └── ubuntu-browsers.d          10.4 Kb
│   ├── cache                          1.1 Mb

PS /etc> $hierarchy[0] | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty, MemberSet

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name              MemberType   Definition
----              ----------   ----------
PSStandardMembers MemberSet    PSStandardMembers {DefaultDisplayPropertySet}
CreationTime      NoteProperty datetime CreationTime=12/14/2021 6:16:05 PM
FullName          NoteProperty string FullName=/etc
Hierarchy         NoteProperty string Hierarchy=etc
LastAccessTime    NoteProperty datetime LastAccessTime=12/16/2021 12:40:41 AM
LastWriteTime     NoteProperty datetime LastWriteTime=12/14/2021 6:16:05 PM
Nesting           NoteProperty int Nesting=0
Parent            NoteProperty DirectoryInfo Parent=/
RawSize           NoteProperty double RawSize=358229
Size              NoteProperty string Size=349.83 KB
```
````

Comment: Well-done (checked current GitHub version) however `[PSTreeStatic]::SizeConvert(1152)` returns `1.13 KB` while `[math]::Round(1152/1KB,2)` is `1.12`…

Comment: Thank you @JosefZ, I've updated the code on Github